# Error with run "npm run eject". Error 'Remove untracked files, stash or commit any changes, and try again.'

Tags: git, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I have try lot's of things to solve this error.

Command:'npm run eject'

```
Remove untracked files, stash or commit any changes, and try again.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! devportalfrontend@0.1.0 eject: `react-scripts eject`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the devportalfrontend@0.1.0 eject script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/deep/.npm/_logs/2018-02-18T17_05_02_924Z-debug.log
```

How can help to solve this problem..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have tried this command it's worked:

```
git add .
git commit -am "Save before ejecting"
```

and then try again.

Answer (score 9):

Uninstalling react-scripts and installing react-scripts-cssmodules solved the problem

```
npm uninstall react-scripts
```

And then

```
npm install react-scripts-cssmodules
```

then

```
 npm run eject
```

Add it the git changes

```
git add .
git commit -am "Save before ejecting"
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to commit your changes before running eject:

```
git add .
```

```
git commit -am "change messages before running eject"
```

Now, Try

```
npm run eject
```

Comment: nice & easy. Works..! thanks

Answer (score 4):

This says in the message that you have untracked files that means that they are not being monitored by your VCS. Hence add and commit them before you eject.

If you are using Visual Studio Code:

- Just click on the third icon (Source Control), below the magnifying glass button
- Then click on the tick mark, if it asks to automatically stage your changes Click Yes
- Add your commit message and then you are done

[image]

Try ejecting again,

```
npm run eject
```

Should work just fine. Happy Hacking!

Answer (score 2):

It is because you having the changed files

so initiate the new git repo

```
git init
```

then add all files to git

```
git add .
```

once added commit the files

```
git commit -am "Saving before ejecting"
```

now you can eject the project using below command

```
npm run eject
```

Happy Coding !!!!!!!

Comment: I can't use git add . without initiating new git if any other git already initialized. Its not mentioned in above answers so i posted here. This solves my problem

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I found the solution here.

### follow this may be it will helpful for you.

Step 1.

```
create-react-app yourProjectName
```

step 2.

```
cd yourProjectName
```

step 3.

```
npm uninstall react-scripts
```

step 4.

```
npm install react-scripts-cssmodules
```

step 5.

```
git init
```

step 6.

```
git add .
```

step 7.

```
git commit -am "ejecting"
```

step 8.

```
npm run eject
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to your steps (e.g. why do you need git?).

Comment: when I want to do that I found the above problem, then search google and try different way but nothing happened then I try this and solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just make commit bc commit is necessary before leaving the project

```
PC MINGW64 ~/react/react2/myapp (master)
$ git commit -am "first commit for before ejecting"
```

and Then eject with this command

```
$ npm run eject
```

Answer (score 0):

just delete git file in the project and then run the command: **npm run eject**

in macos if you navigate to inside the project folder

```
CMD + SHIFT + .
```

this will show hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

1, git init and git add .
2, git commit -m 'before eject'
3, yarn eject

- List item

if that code not to solve problem, you can
1, npm uninstall react-scripts
2, npm install react-scripts-cssmodules
3, exec before code

Comment: the other methods:
 1,  rm -rf .git of the root program
 2, npm run eject

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the one that worked for me is
`expo eject`

Answer (score -1):

Check if any of the below tow options work for you :

- **Uninstalling and Re-installing the react-scripts-cssmodules :**

  npm uninstall react-sctipts

  npm install   react-scripts-cssmodules

  npm run eject
- **Committing the changes of the GIT repository** :

  git add .

  git commit -am "Save before ejecting"

If any of the above two solutions do not work, and IF Git is not necessary for your current project, then go to

**Control Panel -> Programs -> Select "*Git*"** 
 and then **UN-INSTALL**.

Now run the "**npm run eject**" again.

It should work fine now.
You can go ahead and reinstall GIT again whenever necessary